# I still don't agree that E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, expected-value

If the two random variable functions are non-independent, then it doesn't make sense why the equation holds true. For example, let's create a table:
\begin{align}
f(x,y) &  \\[5pt]
f(0,0) &= 0.1  \\
f(0,1) &= 0.2  \\
f(1,0) &= 0.2  \\
f(1,1) &= 0.5
\end{align}
where $f_x(0) = f_x(1) = 0.5$
and   $\ \ \ \ f_y(0) = f_y(1) = 0.5$

Therefore, $E[X]=E[Y]=0.5$ for simplicity's sake.

Then, how does $\sum_i \sum_j x_i f(x_i,y_j) = \sum_i x_i f(x_i)$?

I calculate $\sum_i \sum_j x_i f(x_i,y_j)$ as:

$$0(0.1) + 0(0.2) + 1(0.2) + 1(0.5) = 0.7 \ne 0.5 \ne E[X]$$

Please tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: $f_x (0)=0.1 + 0.2 = 0.3 \neq 0.5$.

Comment: Could it be that $f_x(0)=f(0,0)+f(0,1)=0.3$ and likewise for the others and that you have to compute $E(x+y)=\sum_i \sum_j (x_i+y_j) f(x_i,y_j)$ and $E(x)=\sum_i x_i f_x(x_i)$, similar for $E(y)$?

Comment: Here is the proof  of Linearity of Expectation Function https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Linearity_of_Expectation_Function. It's also fit for non-independent random variables.

Comment: "I still don't agree that E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)" .... then I have some nice wagers for you. [Hint: you calculated the $f_x$ and $f_y$ values wrong.]